# Re posicionar elementos de un top navigation

Tags: html, css, css3

¿Cómo va? A la hora de hacer las modificaciones para el responsive tengo un problema con el menú a desplegar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de presionar el menú:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que los elementos se posiciones por debajo de Home, pero no estoy consiguiendo lograrlo. Este es mi css:

```
body{ 
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav{
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #333; 
}

.topnav a{
    float: right; 
    display: block; 
    color: white; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 14px 16px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size: 17px; 
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: white;
}
  
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}
  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}
  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Y así lo tengo en mi html:

```
    <div class="topnav" id="topnavhome">
        <a href="#" class="active" style="float: left;">Home</a> 
        <a href="#">Servicios</a>
        <a href="#">Clientes</a>
        <a href="#">Contacto</a>

        <!-- Esta función en javascript añade el menú hamburguesa para caundo cambia el tamaño de la pantalla -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="funcionMenuHamburguesa()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

¿Cómo lo consigo?

**Actualización:**

Adjunto el `javascript`:

```
function funcionMenuHamburguesa(){
    var x = document.getElementById("topnavhome");

    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, da el codigo completo, con el Javascript incluido, por que no aparece el menu cuando hago la prueba

Comment: listo @coreDeiv

Comment: Brother, encierra los enlaces de servicios, clientes y contactos en un nav y le das absolute a ese nav en Mobile

Comment: Usa position fixed y z-index,